# $\int \int _R {\,dx \,dy \over \sqrt{x^2 +y^2} }$ where $R : \{|x| \le 1; |y| \le 1 \}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

$$\int \int _R {\,dx \,dy \over \sqrt{x^2 +y^2} },$$
where $R : \{|x| \le 1; |y| \le 1 \}$.

My solutions: $$\int \int _R {\,dx \,dy \over \sqrt{x^2 +y^2} }=4\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi \over 4} \int_{r=0}^{\sqrt 2}{r \,dx \,dy \over r}=\sqrt2 \pi$$

Can we do this way?

Comment: This is not correct as you've given the bounds for a circle, not a square

Comment: As Ninad points out, the bounds you gave for $r$ and $\theta$ represent an eighth of a circle with radius $\sqrt{2}$, when the bounds you are given are a square. Secondly, and I know you meant this, $dxdy$ in the second integral should be $drd\theta$.

Comment: Since your boundaries are for a diamond and not a square, you need to use a modified coordinate transformation before using polar easily.  You can make your life easier by doing it just for the first quadrant and quadrupling, since it is symmetric

Comment: @Alan It is a square. $|x|\leq 1$ gives the vertical strip bounded by $x=1$ and $x=-1$, and $|y|\leq 1$ gives the horizontal strip bounded between $y=1$ and $y=-1$. This is a square.

Comment: Right.  Should teach me to post half awake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with symmetry. We can say that

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dydx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 8 \int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac{dydx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Then, to integrate the triangle, we have to find the boundary $x=1$ in polar coordinates

$$1 = x = r\cos\theta \implies r = \frac{1}{\cos\theta} = \sec\theta$$

which means the correct integral is

$$8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_0^{\sec\theta} drd\theta$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: can you please explain why it's 8 times when it is the region of a square?

Comment: @chris how many of these triangles are in the first quadrant? How many quadrants are there?

Comment: Okay, I got you, 2 triangles and 4 quadrant so it's 8 times. Thank you for explaining.